# Spring Boot API Base64 Encoding Error in POST

Tags: java, spring-boot, axios, base64

I am seriously stuck such a point that when I send a POST request via **Axios** js library, I get

> Illegal base64 character 2d error

But when I use swagger UI, the same base64 data is send successfully. Completely the same data I am pretty sure. Because I copy the request content from browser's inspection page and paste it into Swagger-ui page and it works fine.

```
const data = {};
data["newToken"] = btoa(token);
data["oldToken"] = btoa(oldToken);
```

I tried all I can do. Even encoding the content to base64.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/token/sync")
@ApiOperation(value = "", notes = "Sync web socket token")
public void syncSocketToken(@RequestBody  SyncTokenRequest request) {

    tokenService.syncToken(request.getNewToken());
    tokenService.removeToken(request.getOldToken());
}
```

This is my controller.

```
export const messageTokenSyncApi = async data =>
  Api.post("services/pobnotification/api/v1/items/token/sync", data);

/// Api.js is here ///

import axios from "axios";
import * as AxiosLogger from "axios-logger";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "/",
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
});

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(AxiosLogger.requestLogger);
}

export default axiosInstance;
```

And the request payload is here. Token strings are base64 encoded.

```
{"newToken":"Y3l0S2qX05.....1T21mN0c1RFcxSg==","oldToken":""}
```

I am looking forward to read your idea about it.

Thanks

Comment: can you please show how you are doing you axios request, also show the request done from chrome developer pane (F12), show us what you are actually sending from the browser to the spring backend.

Comment: I've updated the content of the question. @ThomasAndolf

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to trim (yourString.trim()) the BASE64 encoded string to remove extra linebreaks or such that can be added by some encoders. I had similar problems when I had androids base64-class in one end to encode and spring-related base64-class in the other end to decode.

I'm not very familiar with SyncTokenRequest class etc, but perhaps this could be a clue to help you.